# Django won't let me run migrate because the check function detects references to a new field I am adding

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am adding a new field to a model, but I can't get the migration to work

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: main_language.iso639_1
```

I could only generate the migration file with makemigration by commenting out all references to the new field in my code, but now I can't run migrate without keeping the field commented out.

This is not acceptable as referencing my new field obviously needs to eventually appear in my code and anyone else pulling the latest version of the codebase will have the uncommented code when they attempt to run the migration.

I haven't had this problem before despite adding new fields to models many times, not sure why it is happening this time:

```
# iso639_1 is the new field

class Language(TranslatableMixin, models.Model):
    ENGLISH = 1 # id for English should always be 1
    ISO_HELP_TEXT = _("Please find the correct code at: https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php")

    title = models.ForeignKey('main.Sentence', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='LanguageTitle')
    iso639_2 = models.CharField(max_length=8, help_text=ISO_HELP_TEXT)
    iso639_1  = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, default='', help_text=ISO_HELP_TEXT)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = LanguageManager()
```

Error I receive when trying to run 'python manage.py migrate':

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: main_language.iso639_1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 58, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\lang\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lang import views as core_views
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\lang\views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from main.views import background_tasks
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\main\views\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .assess import *
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\main\views\assess.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .main import move_to_next_mode
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\main\views\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from main.forms import SignUpCourseForm, SelectClassForm
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\main\forms.py", line 25, in <module>
    class InviteDetailsForm(forms.Form):
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\main\forms.py", line 36, in InviteDetailsForm
    label = _('Which language should the invitation email be sent in?'), 
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 758, in __init__
    self.choices = choices
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 775, in _set_choices
    value = list(value)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1068, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: main_language.iso639_1
Finished "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\manage.py migrate" execution.
```

The code raising the error exists in the LanguageManager..

```
class LanguageManager(models.Manager):
    def interface_language_choices(self):
        localizations = [x[0] for x in settings.LANGUAGES]
        return Language.objects.filter(iso639_1__in=localizations)
```

If I comment out the body of **def interface_language_choices(self)** replacing it with a **pass** , I then get errors related to the function giving no return value. Why is it even insisting on running my code just to do a migration?

My migration file:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

def populate_iso(apps, schema_editor):
    Language = apps.get_model('main', 'Language')

    for x in (('eng','en'),('tur','tr'),('rus','ru'),('fra','fr'),('uzb','uz'),('spa','es')):
        L = Language.objects.get(iso639_2=x[0])
        L.iso639_1 = x[1]
        L.save()    


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0030_auto_20180620_1649'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='language',
            name='iso639_1',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, default='', help_text='Please find the correct code at: https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php', max_length=8),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(populate_iso),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant migration? I have the idea that you carry out certain migration tasks that should not be done as long as the column is not added (in a possibly later migration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the FineManual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)):

> Migrations that alter data are usually called “data migrations”; **they’re best written as separate migrations**, sitting alongside your schema migrations.

IOW: split your migration in two - the first one adding the field, the second one filling it with the relevant data.

**But** this is actually not your problem. From your traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\main\forms.py", line 25, in <module>
    class InviteDetailsForm(forms.Form):
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\main\forms.py", line 36, in InviteDetailsForm
    label = _('Which language should the invitation email be sent in?'), 
  File "C:\Users\Win7\OneDrive\Programming\Git\lang\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 758, in __init__
    self.choices = choices
```

Your `InviteDetailsForm` code is obviously making a db query *at the class top-level* to populate choices for a field - I assume something like:

```
class InviteDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    # ...
    something = forms.ChoiceField(
        choice= Language.objects.interface_languages_choices()
        # ...
        )
```

This code is executed when your module is imported (this is normal Python operation - `class` is an executable statement), which leads to your problem. The solution is to [pass the method itself instead of passing it's result](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices):

```
    something = forms.ChoiceField(
        # notice the absence of parens !
        choice= Language.objects.interface_languages_choices, 
        # ...
        )
```

Or to use a `ModelChoiceField` instead of a `ChoiceField` (the former will not force the evaluation of the queryset, while the second does).

> Why is it even insisting on running my code just to do a migration

Because "it" needs to loads the apps and models and url confs, which imports the views, which imports your forms modules, which executes the code at the top level of your form class, which calls your method.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't make a difference, I still get the same error when I try to migrate even when I remove the data migration part.

Comment: @talkingtoaj indeed, I should have read the traceback more carefuly... cf my edited answer (warning: answer based on assumptions and wild guesses since you didn't post the relevant code).

Comment: my....goodness... that is amazingly insightful. I changed the line to choice= Language.objects.interface_languages_choices passing the method instead of its result and problem solved. Brilliant.